# Resizing XAML properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, scaling

Is there a way to have XAML properties scale along with the size of the uielements they belong to?

In essence, I have a control template that I have created too large for it's use/ mainly because I want to use the same control with different sizes. The problem is that I can set the control size to Auto (in the ControlTemplate), however the properties of the intrisic template elements aren't resized: eg StrokeThickness remains at 10 while it should become 1.

It works fine when I apply a ScaleTransform on the template, but that results in a control that's too small when it's actually used: the width/height=Auto resizes the control to the proper size *and then* the scaletransform is applied. So I'm stuff with a sort of nonscalable control.

I'm a bit new to WPF, so there might be a straightforward way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to bind the width and height of the control inside the template to the width and height respectively of the templated control at runtime. Something like:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType={x:Type Button}>
            <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Property=ActualWidth}"
                    Height="{TemplateBinding Property=ActualHeight}">
                <ContentPresenter />
             </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Note that the binding sources are the **FrameworkElement.ActualWidth** and **FrameworkElement.ActualHeight** properties of the templated control. These properties contain the width and height of a control after it has been rendered, which can be different from what has been specified in the **Width** and **Height** properties. This is because the values are ultimately calculated at runtime taking into account the size of any parent controls in the visual tree.

Answer (score 4):

Your description is a bit vague, but it sounds like you'll want to have a ViewBox with the Stretch set to Uniform as the root element of your control.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you can't create a control template for a StackPanel, DockPanel, Grid, or any other container.